# Turn Golang http.Request struct to cURL command

Tags: go, curl

In my debugging process of a microservice, I want to know how my client service request finally looks like, to make sure is the problem from client service or the target service.

For this purpose, I need a tool (or pkg) to turn `http.Request` struct to a cURL command

example of http.Request struct:

```
{
    Method:POST
    URL:https://some-fake-url.com
    Proto:HTTP/1.1
    ProtoMajor:1
    ProtoMinor:1
    Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br]
    Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.9]
    Authorization:[Bearer gkasgjagsljkg]
    Connection:[keep-alive]
    Content-Length:[0]
    Content-Type:[application/json]
    ...
}
```

The client service use this request with `http.DefaultClient.Do()`,

I don't want to manually turn this into a cURL because that may not be valid.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Volker I edited my question hoping that it's clear now, I'm not expecting SO to write me code, and I've also found my answer if you let me write it.

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to know what kind of curl request `http.Request` is using internally? And what if it doesn't use curl, but some different implementation?

Comment: @pptaszni I'm aware that Golang is NOT using cURL under the hood (or internally), curl is just a tool, but I was curious how can I translate my Golang request to another type of request that can be run outside of the Go environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your Golang requests to cURL command with [http2curl](https://github.com/moul/http2curl) pkg like below:

```
import (
    "http"
    "moul.io/http2curl"
)

data := bytes.NewBufferString(`{"hello":"world","answer":42}`)
req, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://www.example.com/abc/def.ghi?jlk=mno&pqr=stu", data)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

command, _ := http2curl.GetCurlCommand(req)
fmt.Println(command)
// Output: curl -X PUT -d "{\"hello\":\"world\",\"answer\":42}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://www.example.com/abc/def.ghi?jlk=mno&pqr=stu
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the package [curling](https://github.com/aoliveti/curling)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aoliveti/curling"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "https://www.google.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("If-None-Match", "foo")

    cmd, err := curling.NewFromRequest(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(cmd)
}
```

output

```
curl -X 'GET' 'https://www.google.com' -H 'If-None-Match: foo'
```